# The attempt to connect to the report server failed error in SSRS Reports

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have install SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2014 Developer edition installed in my machine and use SQL Server 2014 Reporting service.
I get bellow error in report viewer

> The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your
>   connection information and that the report server is a compatible
>   version.
>           The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

and check report server log file and get bellow error

```
Software Usage Metrics initialize failed
```

can ay body let me know what is the possible reason and how can I over come this.

**Web Config**

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="Ext.Net" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
```

**Sample Code**

```
ReportParameter[] repParams = new ReportParameter[1];
                    repParams[0] = new ReportParameter("CatergoryID", "109");

                    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
                    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://pcname/ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER2014");
                   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/folder/reportname";
                    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(repParams);
                    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
                    ReportViewer1.Update();
```

**Sample Markup**

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1"  runat="server" ShowParameterPrompts="false" Height="450" Width="100%" ProcessingMode="Remote"
                        ShowWaitControlCancelLink="false">
```

Comment: Are you sure your reporting server is set correctly and server service is running